# ES5 only: return value when match is found after iterating over various values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-5

I am writing a function to return an `id` based on a few various things aligning. The code mostly works *except* that because there is no `break;` for a `forEach`. I believe I need to use a different filter or find option on the array.

```
function getDefaultId(prod) {
    var defaultId;

    prod.images.forEach( function(image) {
        defaultId = image.isPrimary ? image.id : undefined;
    });

    return defaultId;
}

var prod.images = [
    0: {
        isPrimary: false,
        id: 1234
    },
    1: {
       isPrimary: true,
       id: 1235
    },
    2: {
        isPrimary: false,
        id: 1236
    }
]
```

Essentially I'm trying to return the corresponding `id` for `isPrimary`. The result should be `1236` but I'm getting `undefined` because the forEach is not breaking and thus is resetting the variable to `undefined` on the next iteration.

Comment: Consider using `Array.find()` instead: `prod.images.find(image => image.isPrimary).id;` - (granted this doesn't account for the result not being found).

Comment: Can you not just use a `for` loop?

Comment: You can't use conditionals inside of a foreach statement.

Comment: @staypuftman I'm not sure what you mean by that. You absolutely can use conditionals inside of a foreach statement.

Comment: @TylerRoper - perhaps you can, but it's against the whole concept of iteration. Your ES6 answer was really good. `.filter()` is what I'd probably go with here as it's a reducer, trying to think of how to approach without all the fancy stuff ES6

Comment: @staypuftman Using conditionals inside a `forEach` *"goes against the whole concept of iteration"*...?  These claims are wildly unfounded. Can you imagine not being able to use an `if` statement in a `for` loop? That said, thanks for acknowledging my answer. In ES5, `.filter()` has no early-exit case, as something like `.some()` does - so I'd suggest Nina's answer, personally.

Comment: I think you're just misunderstanding me. You want to use `.forEach()` when you want every result evaluated, but one of the newer array methods like `.some()` will break before going through each result. Both are iterating but forEach is doing some unnecessary work. It really doesn't matter when you've got three items in an array like the OP though.

Comment: @staypuftman I agree with the entirety of that comment, though I feel it necessary to point out how drastically different that is than saying *"conditionals go against the whole concept of iteration"*, when in fact they together are two of the fundamental building blocks of programming :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit early.

```js
function getDefaultId(prod) {
    var defaultId;
    prod.images.some(function (image) {
        if (image.isPrimary) {
            defaultId = image.id;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return defaultId;
}

var prod = { images: [{ isPrimary: false, id: 1234 }, { isPrimary: true, id: 1235 }, { isPrimary: false, id: 1236 } ]};

console.log(getDefaultId(prod));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var images = [
    {
        isPrimary: false,
        id: 1234
    },
    {
       isPrimary: true,
       id: 1235
    },
    {
        isPrimary: false,
        id: 1236
    }
]

let result = images.filter(img => img.isPrimary === true)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and to get an array of objects which have `isPrimary` as true, and then return the `id` of the first item found like so:

```js
function getDefaultId(prod) {
    var primaryImg = prod.images.filter(function(img) {
      return img.isPrimary;
    });

    return primaryImg[0].id;
}

var prod = {};
prod.images = [{isPrimary: false, id: 1234 }, {isPrimary: true, id: 1235}, {isPrimary: false, id: 1236}];

console.log(getDefaultId(prod));
```

Comment: If you're only concerned with the first of the primary items, then you should consider exiting out of the array after finding it. No use iterating through the entire array after you've already found what you want :)

Comment: @TylerRoper Good point, `.some` is probably the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try using `map`.

```
var images = [
    {
        isPrimary: false,
        id: 1234
    },
    {
       isPrimary: true,
       id: 1235
    },
    {
        isPrimary: false,
        id: 1236
    }
];

function getDefaultId() {
  var defaultId;
  images.map(function (image) {
    if (image.isPrimary) {
      defaultId = image.id;
    }
  });
  return defaultId;
}

console.log(getDefaultId());
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Also, I don't think `.map` is the right move here. Any object that had `isPrimary: true` is just replaced by an integer (the `id`), but any that *aren't* remain unchanged. The result is a mixed array of objects and integers.

Comment: instead of returning i am console logging the the id of the object that has image.isPrimary equal to true.

Comment: I will edit it in order to return the defaultId value.

Comment: I've removed my downvote as it now functions properly, but still, `.map` is not the way to go here. You're using it as a way to iterate through an array, but `.map` does much more than that. It also iterates through the *entirety* of the array, even after finding the result it wants. I.e., if you have an array of 5,000 items, and the first one is primary, why loop through the other 4,999? Consider `.some`, as in Nina's answer.

Comment: I agree, Nina's is a better answer.